# "Brownian motion" related to the $p$-Laplace operator

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, elliptic-pde

The link between the Brownian motion and the Laplace operator is well-known.

What stochastic process plays an analogous role with respect to the $p$-Laplace operator?

Comment: It's an interesting question.  One piece of the question would be in what sense the role is "analogous".  There's a standard notion of the generator of a Markov process, but this always yields a linear operator.

Comment: The following reference by Peres and Sheffield discusses a counterpart of Brownian motion for the p-Laplacian https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1221656864

Comment: Search for tug of war with noise